# Setting model in Angular $scope is not binding to multiselect ddl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multiselect dropdown bound to an array of objects ($scope.selectedProperties):

```
<select id="propertyDdl" multiple="multiple" 
ng-model="selectedProperties" 
ng-options="account.property_name group by account.client_name for account in accountInfo">
</select>
```

(accountInfo is a scope property containing an array of objects):

```
[{client_name:"Client 1", is_demo:false, property_name:"Prop 1"},
{client_name:"Client 2", is_demo:false,  property_name:"Prop 2" },
{client_name:"Client 3", is_demo:false,  property_name:"Prop 3" }]
```

on a certain event, I store the array of selected items:

```
$scope.updateSessionProperties = function () {
    CachingService.cachedSelectedProperties = $scope.selectedProperties;
};
```

...Then reapply them later:

```
if(CachingService.cachedSelectedProperties && CachingService.cachedSelectedProperties.length>0){
    $scope.selectedProperties = CachingService.cachedSelectedProperties; 
}
```

the array of objects (selectedProperties) it is bound to is structured identical to accountInfo:

```
[{client_name:"Client 1", is_demo:false, property_name:"Prop 1"}, 
{client_name:"Client 2", is_demo:false,  property_name:"Prop 2" }]
```

with no luck... the dropdown list displays "none selected" even though the scope property it is bound to is the identical object.  I have tried executing $scope.$apply() as well, but the select element will not rebind.

Comment: Where is the `accountInfo` being defined?

Comment: $scope.accountInfo is defined at the beginning of the $scope and is an array identical to the model:[{client_name:"Client 1", is_demo:false, property_name:"Prop 1"}, 
{client_name:"Client 2", is_demo:false,  property_name:"Prop 2" }, 
{client_name:"Client 3", is_demo:false,  property_name:"Prop 3"... }] Interestingly, if I push an item from accountInfo into selectedProperties, the binding DOES work, however pushing the identical item into selectedProperties any other way fails.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), I would suggest the following:

```
<select
    id="propertyDdl"
    multiple="multiple"
    ng-model="userSelectedProperties"
    ng-options="account.property_name group by account.client_name for account in selectedProperties">
</select>
```